# MediaWiki word thesaurus graph extension

Tags: mediawiki, data-visualization, mediawiki-extension, thesaurus

I use [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) on Ubuntu. Is there a way to create `word thesaurus graph` from categories of MediaWiki? For example like this image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you've found since then, but for the sake of the interweb, VIKI seems to do the job :

VIKI (Visualization and Knowledge Integration):

[image: VIKI (Visualization and Knowledge Integration)]

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VIKI

> VIKI (Visualization and Knowledge Integration) is a D3-based directed force layout graph visualization of the structure of a wiki. In a VIKI graph, graph nodes represent individual wiki pages or web pages, while links between nodes indicate page links (i.e. one page has a hyperlink to another page, e.g. of the form [[Other Page]]). These links are directional, where the direction of the link indicates which page links to which. If two pages link to each other, the link is bidirectional. We say two pages are linked on a VIKI graph if there is a link between their nodes on the graph, i.e. either of the two pages links to the other, or they link to each other. Some wiki pages also have hyperlinks to external web pages; these pages are also displayed on the VIKI graph (with a generic wi-fi icon), but interaction with these pages is limited.
>
> The graph is pannable and zoomable using either the mouse scroll action or the zoom bar located at the bottom of the graph. Individual nodes may be dragged around and rearranged as well; the D3 graph automatically revises node positions to a local equilibrium state whenever nodes are dragged.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.